# Ajax is posting to the wrong controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So, i have a slightly strange issue. I have the following ajax:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Auth")',
        data: $('form').serialize()
    }).done(function (res) {
        if (res.status === "success") {
            $('form').hide();
            $("#msg").show();
        }
        if (res.status == "failure") {
            $("errormsg").show();
        }
    });
});
```

And then i have two controllers that takes a `[Httppost]`

This is my controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(USERS model)
{
    MySqlContext db = new MySqlContext();
    if (db.USERS.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EMAIL == model.EMAIL) != null)
    {
//Code
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() => { EmailService.SendEmail(model.EMAIL, "Password retreival", body); });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return Json(new { status = "success" });             
    }
        return Json(new { status = "failure" });
}
[Httppost]
public ActionResult Login(USERS model)
{
//Code
    if (model.EMAIL != null && pwDec == true)
    {
            return Json(new { status = "success" });
    }
    return Json(new { status = "error" });
}
```

I have removed some code in order to make my question more transparent. What happens, is that if my conditional expression in ForgotPassword `== null`, my code returns json "success" even though it should be "failure", and logs me in..

The program is using claims based authentication, and i suspect that it is the reason why i for some strange reason gets logged in.

I suspect that my ajax url is correct? Anyway, i dont understand why i get logged in, when i post to my `ForgotPassword` controller in my ajax.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please press F12 and check the URL to which it is sending request

Comment: Assuming you have the correct data attributes on your view models, `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Json(new { status = "error" });`

Comment: It first calls my `ForgotPassword` controller, and then it calls my `login` controller

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code and Model information as well?